# delay-google-cloud-console-app-verification for 2 weeks without feedback

Tags: google-cloud-platform, verification

i had create on google cloud console app that require access to google calendar and google sheet . google drive
i had submit my app for verification , now pass about 2 weeks without any feedback from google team

how can follow my app verification or know if require more data to submit and when expect my app to be verified

after 2 weeks without any feedback from google team

how can follow my app verification or know if require more data to submit and when expect my app to be verified

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot help you on StackOverflow. Your only options are to wait or change the scopes your application requires so that verification is automatic. My guess is that you have requested [restricted](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/restricted-scope-verification) scopes. Also, read this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/13463073?visit_id=638416266788701638-3777239374&rd=1).

Comment: my scope is sensitives , and if i changed or removed this scope so why i need the application , the scope is calendar , and google sheet

Comment: Did you read the section on "[Sensitive scope verification](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/sensitive-scope-verification)"? If your app is accessing a user's data, then you must wait for your app to complete the verification process. The Google verification team does not provide a method to contact them and we cannot help you with that process.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all please consider this platform as code/error related issue.
but here it is any way (i understand as you are new).

it is mostly expected and normal . depending on any given time  the verification team may have pending requests because of this your verification is taking longer ,also  i don't know about current situation but back in month they been giving covid 19 and government related app priority , for now it is best to contact them directly either via chat /call or email what ever you find easy from your console directedly.

its normal to wait for about  7  days.

Comment: how can contact them i didn't found any contact section , if possible to share their contact

Comment: in your console ,top-right corner you can see a question mark icon press it , see if the related term match with your question then go through the articles/community post else scroll down and you will see contact , email/chat option . you can go to [android-developer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#topic=3450769)

Comment: i working with web application not andriod play store

Comment: my bad , did not sleep well , any way still there is contact us button there .

Comment: if did not found ,post the screen-shot